# GridFS GET route not working - hangs without returning file or throwing an error

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I have been trying to build a basic app to upload images to MongoDB using GridFS. I have been following a few tutorials. Using this code I am able to upload images and can view them in MongoDB compass however I am not able to fetch either all the files or specific files, each time I run a GET request my browser (http://localhost:5000) just hangs (same with Postman app).

I have been reading all day around GridFS and I don't understand what is causing the issue.

I do not get any errors in the terminal or any status coming back. I have tested on Chrome and Safari.

Code is below, expecting that when I navigate to http://localhost:5000/files/:filename to get the specified file back as json

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require("multer");
const { GridFsStorage } = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const { timeStamp } = require("console");

const app = express();

// Middleware

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Mongo URI

const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

// create MONGO connection

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Initialise GridFS stream

let gfs;

conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
});

// Create storage object

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route GET /
// Loads form

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

// @route POST /upload
// @desc Uploads file to DB

app.post("/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ file: req.file });
  console.log({ file: req.file });
});

app.get("/files/:filename", (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: "No file exists",
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file);
  });
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}, ${mongoURI}`)
);
```